# How to execute a LOC only if a function is defined in another file in C++

Tags: c++, preprocessor

so lets say we have the following structure:

```
/folder
    -main.cpp
    -/folder2 
          -/folder4

    -/folder3
          -/folder5
             -somefile.cpp
```

I now have some lines in main.cpp which i only want to execute/compile if a certain function in somefile.cpp is defined, since folder2 and folder3 do not always get compiled. Its always one of them. Is there a way to do this in C++

Comment: I guess you could tell your executable to `dlopen` itself and look for the function at runtime, but what is the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "if a certain function in somefile.cpp is defined". Does the content of that file look different if and if not? If yes, please show both versions.

Comment: I think you need to go one step backward in the causal chain. I.e. whatever causes the function to be defined or not, it should also influence whether the few lines in main.cpp are defined. For that, please show demonstrate what/how decides whether the function in defined. If you are lucky it might e.g. be a switch defined in a header and you can include that header and use the same dependency.

Comment: What decides "folder2 and folder3 do not always get compiled"? Can that interact with the call that compiles main.cpp